# Fatal Error Unsupported operand types in Gtm.php

Tags: category

I am getting White screen to access new category and the follow error in **nginx/log/error.log:**

```
[error] 1691#0: *80122 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in /usr/share/nginx/sites/exanple/app/code/local/MyVersion/GoogleTagManager/Block/Gtm.php on line 43" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /utensilios-cozinha/categoria-teste HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

The line 43 have:

```
$data = $data + $this->_getTransactionData();
```

Check my code Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/EeCT9gh5

Answer (score 2):

In your function `_getDataLayer()` variable `$data` taken as array.

```
 $data = array();
```

In your syntax

```
$data = $data + $this->_getTransactionData();
```

Function `$this->_getTransactionData()` is not returning valid data. I think it is not returning an array. Try to debug what data you are getting by this `$this->_getTransactionData()` function.

If you do like `$data = array() + 1;` it will give you an error **Fatal error: Unsupported operand types**

Comment: How i fix this? += ? All the other pages works fine, just the new category show this problem

Comment: you will need to check what you are getting by this function $this->_getTransactionData()

Comment: This function return a dataLayer:  'event' => 'transaction',
                    'transactionId' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                    'transactionDate' => date("Y-m-d").....

Comment: first try to comment line $data = $data + $this->_getTransactionData(); and see if that is working or not

Comment: Commenting the line works fine, the page loads, but the datalayer doesnt work. If i dont edit the code, trying with $data +.. works in other categories. Why does not this page?

Comment: Can you post complete dataLayer in your question which is returning by $this->_getTransactionData() function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30032/discussion-between-akhilesh-patel-and-user2925795).